# How to update column values to database in phpfox project

Tags: phpfox

I need to update the column values to table in phpfox forum module posting new thread  general type. I have found the table name in coding (query) and added values to column but I am not getting col values. Can anybody help?

my **db name** : **munpal**

**table name** : **forum_post**

**colmun name**   : **mark value** (here I need to add my values )

Answer (score 0):

Open `module\forum\include\service\thread\process.class.php` and look `add` function in that.
This function is called when a thread is added you can modify the function according to your need. May this helps you